# Magento 2 - How do I get just the changed data?

Tags: magento2, php

when I try to get the value, I get the old value and the new that just do not get changed at `$this->scopeConfig->getValue`

How to get the current values? Cash tried to clean. Does not help

```
class Config extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
protected $_objectManager;
public $error = true;
private $ch;

public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context, \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager)
{
    $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function getStoreConfig($config_path, $scopeCode = NULL)
{
    return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
        $config_path,
        \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
        $scopeCode
    );
}
}
class Handy extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
public $_objectManager;
public $_conf;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
    \Infomodus\Upslabel\Helper\Config $config
)
{
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
    $this->_conf = $config;

}
public
function setPackageDefParams($itemData = NULL, $storeId, $type = "shipment")
{
 /* It takes the value is not Tube and that which was established for the first time */
    $defParArr_1['packagingtypecode'] = $this->_conf->getStoreConfig('upslabel/packaging/packagingtypecode');
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain how are you changing the "values" and where?

Comment: In the settings there is a drop-down list I change the value and save the settings. But when the code to receive this setting, you get the old value, not the newly installed

Stores->Configuration

Comment: Sorry but the explanation still be vague. I guess that if you are trying to get a configuration value in the same request scope the configuration object could be cached or loaded by a singleton. however. If you improve a little your question showing how and where are you saving and getting the configuration data would be easier to help

Comment: I updated the question

Answer (score 0):

I realized what a mistake. I have here `<section id = "config_upslabel" translate = "label" type = "text" sortOrder = "330" showInDefault = "1" showInWebsite = "1" showInStore = "1">` id was incorrect
just needed upslabel

thanks for the help